# Submit a Form to Custom URL in Laravel 4

Tags: forms, url, laravel, laravel-4

I have a simple form which allows the User to enter `from_date` and `to_date`.Lets say a user enters `2014-09-01` and `2014-09-10` respectively.

How can I get this form submit to a URL `../from_date/2014-09-01/to_date/2014-09-10`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that but if you need to do something like this, you need to submit to standard class Controller and then resubmit it using redirection:

```
public function resubmit() {
   Redirect::to('/from_date/'.Input::get('from_date').'/to_date/'.Input::get('to_date'))->withInput();
}
```

But to be honest I don't know why you try to do that. Usually you post data to static url and display content using dynamic urls with pretty urls.

Comment: Thanks Marcin for your response. The reason I want to submit the user input like this I want to take advantage of the pretty url. I create a route : ../from_date/{from_date}/to_date/{to_date} which will pull all the posts posted between from and to dates. What do you suggest is the best way to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Does that mean that Pretty Urls can only work if we were to use them as a link. How can we use a User Input as a parameter to the pretty URL.  Thanks much for your help.

Comment: @ComradeRaj You can make redirection to pretty url as I showed you above

Answer (score 0):

To change the URL once the page has already loaded, you will need to use javascript, as you won't be able to do this using Laravel/PHP because you need access to the dates, which are only selected after the page has loaded.

If your form is similar to:

```
<form id="dateForm" onsubmit="return submitDateForm()">
  <input type="text" id="from_date" name="from_date">
  <input type="text" id="to_date" name="to_date">
</form>
```

Assuming you are using POST for the form submission, and have already imported jQuery, then insert into your view (or a separate .js file which you import) the following jQuery:

```
function submitDateForm() {
  var from_date = $( '#from_date' ).val();
  var to_date = $( '#to_date' ).val();

  //Send the request
  var request = $.post("../from_date/" + from_date + "/to_date/" + to_date);

  //prevent the form from submitting itself normally
  return false;
}
```